# No response in browser but getting 401 in postman

Tags: javascript, java, cors

I'm calling an API with a JWT. When the token expires or when I send an invalid token, I get a 401 in postman, but when I do it in browser, I get a "Network error". **And it works when the token is valid.**

I use axios to call the API and the `error.response` is undefined. When I stringify the error object in `catch` I see something like this:

```
{
    message :   'Network Error',
    name    :   'Error',
    stack   :   'Error: Network Error\n    at createError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:83:14)'
    }
```

I get 200 in the `OPTIONS` request, but in the main `GET` request I get the above error. This is probably because of CORS. But I don't know what to change. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origins` is `*`.

I don't understand why I don't get the 401 in browser. Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Screenshot of network tab:

[image]

Options:

[image]

Comment: What about posting the code that makes the request and the code that respond to this request?

Comment: You need to post some code here. Just having the request screenshots won't do.

Answer (score 1):

Your server is probably not setting `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true` to allow origin access to authorized users.

Comment: it is set to true

Comment: @Abhi https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you actually have a bug. It's just that axios throws on all 4xx responses by default. Try the following:

```js
axios.get("...", { validateStatus(status) { return true; } })
```

Answer (score -1):

To fix it up, try add other Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) headers. Check them at
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS